# Python - change value of list item

Tags: python, arrays, error-handling

My code is as follows with comments. it runs fine until it comes to changing the value of a list item i.e. data[x][y] = something.

```
Tdata = cursor.fetchall() #Get data from MYSQL database
data = list(Tdata) #Convert into list...not sure if absolutely required
APIData = APIDataList()
MPLlat = 0.0
MPLLon = 0.0
RadiusOI = 15

for i in (range(0,len(data))):
    MPLCount = 0
    MPLlat = data[i][2]
    MPLLon = data[i][3]
    MPLCount = CountofbikesnearMPL(MPLlat, MPLLon, RadiusOI)
    if MPLCount>0:
        data[i][4] = MPLCount #ERROR: here is where the error is kicking in. 
                              #get error "tuple' object does not support 
                              #item assignment"
```

I really cant figure out why this is happening and have tried googling but with no success. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
C

Comment: Can you print out `data[0]` for us and edit your question with the results please?

Comment: thanks for the quick response guys....
print (data[0]) gives
(1, 'Ealing', Decimal('51.495557600000000000000000000000'), Decimal('-0.255182700000000000000000000000'), 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is cleaner to write it using `enumerate`:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(data):
    # MPLCount = 0  - I suppose it is unnecessary since you overwrite the value below
    MPLlat = elem[2]
    MPLLon = elem[3]
    MPLCount = CountofbikesnearMPL(MPLlat, MPLLon, RadiusOI)
    if MPLCount > 0:
        data[i] = elem[:4] + (MPLCount,) + elem[5:]
```

Is there a reason you name variables and functions `ThisWay`? If not, it would be nice if you follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and name them `this_way`. Anyway be consistent and don't mix two styles together.

Comment: Assuming your comment with the tuple structure you can write just `data[i] = elem[:4] + (MPLCount,)` since `elem[4]` is the last one in your tuple

Comment: cheers for the advise, really appreciate it.
reg why i write my variables like that, well...i guess im not versed into the pros and cos of either. Im rolling with naming variables as something easily understood by me. But definitely something i should look into...and will. Thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.fetchall()` [returns a list of tuples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).

That means that `data[i]` will be a `tuple`, which is by definition immutable. If you want to modify `data[i]`, you will need to turn your tuples into lists

```
data = [list(row) for row in Tdata]
```

or replace the entire row via tuple concatenation

```
data[i] = data[i][:4] + (MPLCount,) + data[i][5:]
```

Comment: Was literally about to submit this as an answer line for line.

Comment: yep...data = [list(row) for row in Tdata] worked a charm..

love this community. Many thanks guys